# Cannot parse walking routes in Osm2po

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

I really am at a loss with trying to figure out how to parse only walking routes using OSM2PO.

I've modified the config file to add foot to the routes which can be walked along, as follows:

```
wtr.tag.highway.motorway =       1,  11, 120, car
wtr.tag.highway.motorway_link =  1,  12, 30,  car
wtr.tag.highway.trunk =          1,  13, 90,  car
wtr.tag.highway.trunk_link =     1,  14, 30,  car
wtr.tag.highway.primary =        1,  15, 70,  car|foot
wtr.tag.highway.primary_link =   1,  16, 30,  car|foot
wtr.tag.highway.secondary =      1,  21, 60,  car|foot
wtr.tag.highway.secondary_link = 1,  22, 30,  car|foot
wtr.tag.highway.tertiary =       1,  31, 40,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.tertiary_link =  1,  32, 20,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.residential =    1,  41, 40,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.road =           1,  42, 50,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.unclassified =   1,  43, 50,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.service =        1,  51, 5,   car|bike
wtr.tag.highway.living_street =  1,  63, 7,   car|bike|foot   
wtr.tag.highway.pedestrian =     1,  62, 5,   car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.track =          1,  71, 10,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.path =           1,  72, 10,  car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.cycleway =       1,  81, 15,  bike
wtr.tag.highway.footway =        1,  91, 5,   car|foot
wtr.tag.highway.steps =          1,  92, 5,   car|foot
wtr.tag.route.ferry =            2,   1, 10,  ferry
wtr.tag.route.shuttle_train =    2,   2, 50,  rail|car
wtr.tag.railway.rail =           3,   3, 50,  rail
```

I've also changed

```
# only convert ways with one of these flags

wtr.finalMask=foot
```

As opposed to being

```
wtr.finalMask=car
```

The problem is that Osm2po is still not converting routes which I've specified it to convert by defining those types of route as "foot". I'm getting an output which contains only residential streets for some reason.

Is there something else which needs changing in the configuration file that I'm missing?

Comment: Your config looks okay, so there must be sth. different which causes this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Carsten. I'll try and re-download the OSM file and see if this works.

Comment: I've managed to resolve the issue, and it was simply that it was taking a long time to load the data into QGIS, presumably as the result of a slow postgres connection. (only parts of the network loaded initially and it took a long time for the entire network to be displayed).

Comment: I was also wondering, do you know of a way to edit the osm data to include routes that don’t exist in the original osm.pbf file? It’s just that some of my work requires the analysis of roads which don’t currently exist. I’m also having issues with routing foot routes on some trunk roads that have footpaths on them. Is there a way of defining trunk roads to parse whilst leaving others out?